# Android, DocumentProvider, ParcelFileDescriptor, override getStream()

Tags: android, security, encryption, document-provider

I am writing my DocuemtnProvider for Android OS. My application works with encrypted files. And i should return ParcelFileDescriptor on openDocument method.

**I don't want store temp decrypted file. I Just want to override function like getStream() to return CipherInputStream.**

Can anyone help me ?

Here is some code:

```
public static ParcelFileDescriptor prepareFileDescriptor(FileEntry entryForOpening, String mode, Handler handler) throws IOException {
    int parsedMode = ParcelFileDescriptor.parseMode(mode);
    File realFile = FileCache.get().fileFromRelCachePath(entryForOpening);
    //TODO decrypt to temp set it into listener
    FileDescriptorListener listener = new FileDescriptorListener(entryForOpening, parsedMode);
    return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(realFile, parsedMode, handler, listener);
}
```

Comment: see: `openPipeHelper (Uri uri, String mimeType, Bundle opts, T args, PipeDataWriter<T> func)`

Comment: @pskink , How can it help to me? openPipeHelper returns 2 ParcelFileDescriptor.

Comment: "returns 2 ParcelFileDescriptor" what do you mean? what is 2?

Comment: Sorry. my mistake. Anyway how should it help to me?

Comment: from docs: A helper function for implementing openTypedAssetFile(Uri, String, Bundle), for creating a data pipe and background thread allowing you **to stream generated data** back to the client.

Comment: It is content provider. I just returning ParcelFileDescripter and other application just openning a stream.  I want to replace default stream with my.

Comment: yes i know what you want to do, that is what openPipeHelper is for